# Git: How to check which files exist (and their content) in a shared (bare) repository?

Tags: git, git-bare

I created a shared repo by:

```
git init --bare my_project.git
```

At some point, another user updated this repo with his changes (using `git push`).

How could I check which files are exist now in the shared repo and what is their content ?

In a local repo, I could do just `ls` and `cat <some file>`, but in the shared repo there is no working directory...

Comment: Why don't you just clone that bare repo to a normal repo?

Comment: I could, but I want to know for learning purpose if there is an easy way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the files in the tree of a particular commit with `git ls-tree`, for example:

```
git ls-tree -r master
```

... would show the files in the tree of the commit at the tip of the master branch.  Then, to "cat" a particular file, you can do:

```
git show master:docs/README
```

... supposing the `master` branch had a file called `docs/README`.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks! BTW, Did you mean `git ls-tree` on the first line?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko: oops, yes indeed - thanks for the correction.